# Pause while loop and do something else in Matlab

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I created a GUI in Matlab and one of the buttons the user supposed to press at the beginning has a while loop in it. I am taking frames one by one in this while loop. My problem is that I want the user to be able to pause this process (not to stop completely), so I added a pause button and I am changing a flag as this button is pressed. I need to put a code inside this matlab that will pause the loop procedure as pause button is pressed once, and will continue to the loop process when pause button is pressed again. I tried

```
if flag==1 
   pause on; 
else 
   pause off 
end;
```

But I saw that "pause on;" does not pause a while loop. Is there a function or method that I can use? In addition, I want other buttons to be able to work when code is in pause mode; for example another button displays some words, so when in pause mode, if this display words button is pressed, it must display the words on screen. I tried using "waitfor" but it stopped everything and this display button didn't work. 
I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Try `help pause`  as `pause on` is not the command to initiate a pause.

Comment: Could you give us a code sample of what the while loop looks like?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simple to save the current status, break the while loop, let the user do what he wants, and then start another while loop from the saved point when the user activity stops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use MATLAB's [WAITFOR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitfor.html) function to do this.

Comment: In Matlab' help, it says; "While waitfor prevents its caller from continuing, callbacks that respond to various events (for example, pressing a mouse button) can still run, unaffected by waitfor." However as I tried it in my GUI system, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are looking for

```
while flag == 1
   % Get/process your user input here

   % Finish checking user input
   pause(1) %Check every second, can of course be reduced
end
```

Comment: As I use Pause from time to time, pause(1) would only pause my system for a second. I want my system to pause until I send a command to stop pausing. Also when the system is on Pause, I want other buttons to work some other functions.

Comment: For the first part, I assumed that the user pressing the button sets the flag to one, I have edited my post accordingly. For the second part, if everything is still supposed to work it is not clear what exactly you want to pause.